# Android KotlinRx API call making continuously in background

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I am new to Rx and I am making one API call using Rx. It is working but the problem is that it is continuously making the API after I received response or error. I am using the MVVM pattern.

Here is my code how I am observing result in View Model:

```
val usersList = getGitHubUsersUseCase.getUsers(since.toInt())

        usersList?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe({
                if (it.error == null) {
                    var sinceState = SinceState(since, since.isNotEmpty(), it.users)
                    stateLiveData.postValue(sinceState)
                } else {
                    var sinceState =
                        SinceState(since, since.isNotEmpty(), emptyList(), it.error?.message)
                    stateLiveData.postValue(sinceState)
                }
            }, {
                var sinceState = SinceState(since, since.isNotEmpty(), emptyList(), it.message)
                stateLiveData.postValue(sinceState)
            })
```

How do I stop observing once I received a response or an error? Am I missing something?

If I don't stop this continuously making calls, then it makes too many API calls and server start returning:

> HTTP 403 forbidden

Comment: are you having a retry mechanism in case of error. the code looks alright

Comment: @Raghunandan No. I don't have. if it success but still it is making more API calls.

Comment: put break points and debug. also dispose your observable in onCleared method to prevent leaks.

Comment: I already tried this it is coming it is stopping at that point continuously..

Answer (score 1):

To get a response only once, use the 'Single' type. You can convert your data stream to a Single using

`val usersList = getGitHubUsersUseCase.getUsers(since.toInt()).firstOrError()`

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you

Comment: I din't get you